# Download a list of files from "wget" with an script gives an error

Tags: bash, files, wget, download

I'm trying to download a list of files with specified filenames with wget. Since it doesn't have this option with `-i` I've written a simple script for it:

```
#!/bin/bash
  
FILENAME="list.txt"

LINES=$(cat $FILENAME)

IFS=$'\n'
for LINE in $LINES
do
    wget $LINE
done
```

And this is the contents of list.txt:

```
-O file1.mp4 https://URL_1
-O file2.mp4 https://URL_2
-O file2.mp4 https://URL_3
```

But it shows me **this error:**

```
wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Quoting is a problem. In this case, wget gets "-O file1.mp4 https://URL_1" as one parameter. Not several parameters, "-O", "file1.mp4" and the URL "https://URL_1". This can be observed via strace, filter for execve: `strace -e execve wget -O file1.mp4 https://URL_1` versus `strace -f -e execve ./multiwget` (with multiwget beeing your script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the quoting-problems (I mentioned in the comment), you can read the file in a while-loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME="list.txt"

while read -r LINE; do
    wget $LINE
done < $FILENAME
```

Mind the bad style of leaving out double-quotes around $LINE. Usually you want to enclose variables in double-quotes to prevent splitting.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Can you clarify more why my script doesn't work?

Comment: I did clarify in the comment (to your post). Try the strace-commands and have a look at the execve-lines. How from the script you won't give several parameters to wget, but just one string which wget can't understand.